# const char to SQLCHAR error

Tags: c++, sql, windows

The SELECT statement is a const char and "query" has to be a `SQLCHAR*` I've tried reinterpreting the cast but that doesn't seem to work.  The code runs, even with this error, but I would like to get rid of the error.  The line:

```
SQLCHAR* query = "SELECT tblIP.[IPAddress], tblIP.[IPStatus], tblIP.[IPType] FROM tblIP ORDER BY tblIP.[IPAddress] ASC;";
```

The Error:

> IntelliSense: a value of type "const char *" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "SQLCHAR *"

Comment: What type is `SQLCHAR` a typedef for? `wchar_t`?

Comment: What if you try `SQLCHAR const* query = ...;`?

Comment: Didn't work, see my answer below, I have to wait 7 Hours too officialy post it!

Comment: Your question said you had already tried that...

Comment: I did but not in that way.  I tried this reinterpert_cast<SQCHAR*>()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SQLCHAR* query = (SQLCHAR *)"SELECT tblIP.[IPAddress], tblIP.[IPStatus], tblIP.[IPType] FROM     tblIP ORDER BY tblIP.[IPAddress] ASC;";
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, SQLCHAR can mean tons of different things. You have to at least mention what API you are using... Perhaps this is just a wide-char problem? Try this one:

```
SQLCHAR* query = L"SELECT tblIP.[IPAddress], tblIP.[IPStatus], tblIP.[IPType] FROM tblIP ORDER BY tblIP.[IPAddress] ASC;";
```

Comment: Thank you, Tried that as well. Not working. SQLCHAR* means char*, when I do change it to char* the error goes away, then shows up further down the code, because query is an SQLCHAR*.                 rc = SQLPrepare(hStmt, query, SQL_NTS);

Comment: ITS HAMMERTIME!!!!  SQLCHAR* query = (SQLCHAR *)"SELECT tblIP.[IPAddress], tblIP.[IPStatus], tblIP.[IPType] FROM tblIP ORDER BY tblIP.[IPAddress] ASC;";

Comment: @ME-dia: re-interpretation of that type there is sort of lame. It obviously doesn't mean `char *`, so first thing you have to do is figure out what it means.

Comment: everywhere I searched it says that SQCHAR" means char*.....whether lame or not, it works. I've been working for 2 days on this problem. I'm willing to listen if you have an unlame, not so lame solution.

Comment: @ME-dia: usually it is `char *` or `wchar_t *`, but could also be a structure with length and char array inside. It depends.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
char select_statement[] = "SELECT tblIP.[IPAddress], tblIP.[IPStatus], tblIP.[IPType] FROM tblIP ORDER BY tblIP.[IPAddress] ASC;";
```

Notice the [] after the variable name.

Or:

```
std::string select_statement = "SELECT tblIP.[IPAddress], tblIP.[IPStatus], tblIP.[IPType] FROM tblIP ORDER BY tblIP.[IPAddress] ASC;";
// And pass select_statement.c_str() to your function.
```

The issue is that the function that requires `char *` wants a variable, an array, a mutable area of text.  String literals have the type `const char *` which is a pointer to constant data.

The compiler is complaining that you are passing a pointer to constant data to a function that wants a pointer to **mutable** data.